# How do I do nothing for the last else statement, and move on to the next part of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

What should I do

If I input "a   a" and shift it once I expect it to return "b   b" however I get an error
 I want to the for loop to skip over anything that isn't A-Z, a-z, or 0-9

```
for ( ; i <= w; i++)

    if ((word[i] + rotx) >= 65 && (word[i] + rotx) <=90)
    {
        word[i] += (rotx);
    }
    else if ((word[i] + rotx) >= 97 && (word[i] + rotx) <=122)
    {
        word[i] += (rotx);
    }
    else if ((word[i] + rotx) >= 48 && (word[i] +rotx) <= 57)
    {
        word[i] += (rotx);
    }
    else if ((word[i] + rotx) > 90 && (word[i]+rotx) <97)
    {
        word[i] = 64 + (rotx - (90-word[i]));
    }
    else if ((word[i] + rotx) > 122)
    {
        word[i] = 96 + (rotx - (122-word[i]));
    }
    else if ((word[i] + rotx) > 57)
    {
        word[i] = 47 + (rotx - (57-word[i]));
    }
```

OUTPUT
enter string "a   a"
enter rotations 1

-bash: 1: command not found

Comment: What you have should work. In fact, you can leave the `else` off entirely if you want to.

Comment: you can use `continue` to skip to the next iteration

Comment: just delete the last else lol

Comment: although your code is syntaxically correct, I would *strongly* suggest that you put curly braces to enclose your entire block!

Comment: What do the numbers mean? If these are the ASCII values of characters, you can use char constants directly to make your code more clear. For example, use `'A'` instead of `96`.

Comment: I took out the last else statement, however I I get an error I were to input such a string as "a a"

If i input "a a" and shift it 1,I expect it to output "b b"

Comment: @user, please don't edit your question to ask a different question. If your question got answered and you run into another issue, then mark an answer as accepted and ask another question for the other issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just not use an else. Or use a `continue` statement, if you want the else to be there.

Comment: If `continue` is invoked, then the control would jump to the starting of the loop. If the user wishes to process the data after the `if-else-if` constructs, then I feel `continue` wouldn't be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish your program to just fall through to the next statement, just don't include another `else` part of have an `empty` body as shown by you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last else statement is meant to be < 57.
Apart from that can you not just call the more than 122 and the less than 57 statements and then have else word[i] += (rotx); ??

Sorry, and the between 90 and 97.

Or using a switch statement would be a lot more economical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your last `else` to do nothing, you can use the `continue` keyword inside it. For any conditional you can define the conditional to do nothing by defining an empty code block `{}` for it or by simply ommit the case. If you want a case to do nothing in a `switch` statement, then you either define an empty block `{}` for it or you can use the `break` keyword. Or, you just don't bother with the given case.

As about your edits for your question I am not sure what rotx is in your code and what do you try to achieve. These are not to be omitted when you ask for help, otherwise it's just like saying "my code doesn't work, please help" and you probably know that nobody will want/be able to guess the requirements of your task. So, please take more attention when you specify a task, remember that the community is willing to help you if you help the community to help you.